# bash command check if jmeter test ran successfully

Tags: bash

I run a jmeter test in bash and I get the following output

```
 Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\jbding\Documents\jm Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4 ... end of run @ Tue Aug 31 12:27:57 AEST 2021 (1630376877826)Err: 0 (0.00%)
```

I assign this output to a variable

```
results=$("C:\Users\jbding\Documents\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\jmeter.bat" -n -t "C:\Users\jbding\Documents\Projects\tests.jmx")
```

Basically I want to check if the `results` variable has the `Err: 0` string which means the jmeter tests ran successfully.  To that end I run the following script

```
if [[ $results== *"Err: 0"* ]]; then
    echo "It's there!"
else 
    echo "Its not there"
fi
```

However I always get `Its not there`.  I am new to bash scripting, can someone please tell me whats wrong here ?

Comment: How about capturing `stder` as well. `results=$(... 2>&1)`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if egrep 'error|Error' ./jmeter.log >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "Run had failures."
else
    echo "Run was OK."
```